# Infrared reality

Tags: atmosphere, unusual-color, photography

Is it possible for an earth-like planet to be perceived (by human eyes) in real-time as an infrared photograph? If so, in what conditions? [image]

Comment: Hey Bette. Welcome to World Building. Can I assume that you mean straight human eyes (no modifications, no technology)? If so, how earth-like do you mean? If you mean that everything is the same (biology, lack of technology, planet, etc) as Earth I'm afraid this can't be possible, as... well everything will be the same as us on Earth.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that that's not an infrared photo you've embedded in your question there but just a normal photograph taken with a tinted filter or recolored on a computer, my money's on the later.

Comment: Night vision equipment is [available on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Sports-Outdoors-Hunting-Night-Vision/zgbs/sporting-goods/3304289011/ref=zg_bs_unv_sg_6_3226130011_1). It works in real time. (And that's absolutely not an infrared photo. On an infrared photo the sky and water appear dark, clouds stand out much more than in visible light, and trees and grass appear lighter.)

Comment: unaided CCD sensors are unable to NOT see NIR (near infrared, i.e. what most artsy infrared photos are made in). Consumer (video)cameras that are supposed to image the world 'as we see it' have an IR filter in front of the sensor. You only need to switch that for a VIS-filter, and any old webcam/camcorder can image the NIR world for you.

Comment: @AlexP on an infrared photo color is a surplus. as this is not black and white(or monochrome), my guess is that it was taken by a camera which let a lot of visible light in as well.

Answer (score 4):

We can't see frequencies as long as infrared with our own unaugmented vision.  But you could shift infrared to shorter wavelengths in real time and watch the infrared world as a movie.  That is how **thermal imaging cameras** work.

https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/high-tech-gadgets/nightvision2.htm

> Here's how thermal imaging works:
>
> 1. A special lens focuses the infrared light emitted by all of the objects in view.
> 2. ... The detector elements create a very detailed temperature pattern called a thermogram. It only takes about one-thirtieth of a
>      second for the detector array to obtain the temperature information to
>      make the thermogram... The thermogram created by the detector elements
>      is translated into electric impulses.
> 3. The impulses are sent to a signal-processing unit... that translates the information from the elements into data for the
>      display.
> 4. The signal-processing unit sends the information to the display, where it appears as various colors depending on the intensity of the
>      infrared emission.

[image: thermal image]
https://rangefindernow.com/how-does-thermal-imaging-work/

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, but not by current human eyes

There are [several](https://sciencing.com/animals-can-see-infrared-light-6910261.html) other types of animals that can detect infrared light; in this source, it mentions that bullfrogs use [CYP27c1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYP27C1) to achieve this effect.  Humans already have this gene, so it's just a matter of expressing it in the eye.

We typically process color in [three spectra](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22541/figure/A4615/?report=objectonly), so you may have to sacrifice normal vision to achieve this...unless you're a [tetrachromat](https://www.iflscience.com/brain/tetrachromacy-allows-artist-see-100-million-colors/).  As the link mentions, there are some slightly different neural requirements for *processing* the extra color (versus perceiving it), but it's not unreasonable.  It's hard to say whether we could spontaneously evolve infrared tetrachromacy, but it could theoretically be engineered

Answer (score 2):

There is a colour at the red - infrared border that the monochrome receptors in the human eye are technically capable of seeing, but is normally invisible to us because we see it much, much more dimly than we see the colours that we normally think of as being visible.

On Earth this colour can be made visible by wearing goggles that block red, green and blue light and going outside on a very sunny day (indoor lighting is not bright enough; if you wear the goggles indoors, you just see black). I've tried this. It looks a little odd. You don't see in colour. It's a bit like seeing by moonlight, except that some plants have white leaves and other people's eyes are dark.

Note that this is nowhere near the far infrared range of heat vision goggles, and your perception of it is extremely dim, so you won't see heat this way unless you're looking directly at something that's so hot that it would be visibly glowing very brightly without the goggles.

Conditions to produce a world where this colour is visible without goggles:

- Star so cool that it barely glows
- Planet very close to star
- Atmosphere contains something the blocks the parts of the red spectrum that we most easily see, but doesn't block near infrared